# Youtube embed ios fullscreen landscape and portrait

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation, youtube-api

I have this code

```
htmlString = @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>
body style=\"margin-top:10px;margin-left:8px\"><div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\"><param name=\"movie\" value='%@'></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed id = 'foo' src='%@' type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"708\" height=\"400\"></embed></object></div></body></html>";
```

My apps orientation is all portrait. But i want the youtube embeded in `UIWebView` can have landscape fullscreen. My app has `UITabBar`, and from what i see from apple,

All child view controllers in your `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController` do not agree on a common orientation set.

How can i do that my app is portrait but when playing youtube embed in fullscreen can be in landscape mode??

thanks!